# Passing output from one method to another method java

Tags: java, methods, parameter-passing

I can't seem to grasp this

```
public static void AreaP(double Dia){

    double R = Dia/2.0;
    double A = PI * (R * R);

    System.out.println("The area is: " + A);


public static void PPSI(double Price){


}
```

I have to find the price per square inch so I need to pass the area that I solved for in AreaP into the method PPSI and was wondering if there is a way I could do that because I know you can't pass methods into other methods.

Comment: You could try passing two parameters, instead of just one, like `public static void ppsi(double price, double area)`

Comment: Would it be possible for PSSI to take the Dia as parameter and call AreaP from within PSSI?

Comment: I solved for the area in the previous method but is there a way I can pass the answer from AreaP into PPSI?

Comment: Why don't you just return A from AreaP and call it within PPSI?

Answer (score -1):

```
public static double A=0;

public static void AreaP(double Dia){

    double R = Dia/2.0;
    A = PI * (R * R);

    System.out.println("The area is: " + A);
    System.out.println("The price per square inch is:+PPSI(50))
}


public static double PPSI(double Price){
    return Price/A;

}
```

Making the variable 'A' static and outside the method will allow you to access it from anywhere inside the class or even outside(For.eg, Classname.A )

Comment: It doesn't work. you need to call AreaP method in order set a value for A.

Comment: You cannot set the result of A to a constant since it keeps changing its value.

Comment: 1. He should have a main method calling AreaP()
2. whenever A changes value, we print Price per Sq. inch too. This can fail in muti-threading, but I dont think he has any intention or knowledge of Threads as of now.

Answer (score -4):

How about this:

```
private static final double PI = 3.1416;

public static double areaP(double dia){
    double r = dia/2.0;
    double a = PI * (r * r);

    return a; 
}

public static void  getPricePerSquareInch(double price){
    System.out.print(areaP(75)/price);
}
```

Comment: How does giving a **price** to `areaP` make sense?

Comment: It seems to me that using a value called `price` as the diameter of a circle is probably a very bad idea.